# Drilldown multiple series in HighCharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I'm Using [zoom type selection](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType) (date range region - x axis) for drill down the bubble series and it is working fine so far to drill down multiple event types (y axis) with multiple bubbles to drill down multiple levels.

But recently I added Gantt series ([xrange plugin](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart)) to the chart and even gantt is supporting drilldown for the zoomtype selection when only gantt series exists.

```
I'm using chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(drillDownPoint, series, false); for Bubble and Gantt Series.
```

Now the issue is I wanted to drill down both Bubble and Gantt series together based on the zoom type selection. But the 2nd series is failing at the above mentioned method.

**Note:** This is not about drilldown on single point click.

Explained in detail in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srigopal_sai/9798nnhb/)

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi Kacper, please see the jsfiddle with detailed explanation, please let me know if you need additional details. http://jsfiddle.net/srigopal_sai/9798nnhb/

Comment: If you are trying to get multiple series in drilldown, then you could load more series using `chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[0]);` mulitple times with different series and next call `chart.applyDrilldown();`. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939222/single-series-drilldown-to-multiple-series-highcharts

Comment: I have tried that Kacper, as mentioned in the NOTE, it is not single point drill down, I'm drilling down in zoom selection and I will be having more data points from both series and if choose first point from each series app crashes. I was trying different approach hopping that works. Anyway thanks for helping.