# Single series drilldown to multiple series Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to drill down from a series to multiple series. But the drilldown id seems to be unique on a series, implying that I can't drilldown to multiple series from a single series; just one. How do I get round this?

Comment: If you'd like to see official support for something like this, try casting votes towards [this similar feature](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/6147473-drill-down-charts-that-can-handle-more-than-one-se)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to load series for drilldown in drilldown event using `chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[0]);` mulitple times with different series and next call `chart.applyDrilldown();`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/