# Highcharts multiple series drilldown to multiple series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to generate a Highcharts column chart which initially shows IT costs ( in euro ) of all divisions within our company for each month of the year.

Each division needs to be clickable which drills down to the all the departments within that division; again for each month of the year.

I've added my latest tryout in the following JSFiddle in which the first level works, but the second level does not:

http://jsfiddle.net/r8h1etua/5/

```
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: [
                                'Jan',
                                'Feb',
                                'Mar',
                                'Apr',
                                'May',
                                'Jun',
                                'Jul',
                                'Aug',
                                'Sep',
                                'Oct',
                                'Nov',
                                'Dec'
                            ],
                            crosshair: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Costs ( € )'
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} k</b></td></tr>',
                            footerFormat: '</table>',
                            shared: true,
                            useHTML: true
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Infra',
                            data: [
                                { y: 49.9,      drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 71.59,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 106.4,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 129.2,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 144.0,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 176.0,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 135.69,    drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 148.5,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 216.4,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 194.1,     drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 95.6,      drilldown: 'Div1' },
                                { y: 54.4,      drilldown: 'Div1' }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            name: 'Industry North',
                            data: [
                                { y: 83.6,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 78.8,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 98.5,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 93.4,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 106.0,     drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 84.5,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 105.0,     drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 104.3,     drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 91.2,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 83.5,      drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 106.6,     drilldown: 'Div2' },
                                { y: 92.3,      drilldown: 'Div2' }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            name: 'Industry South',
                            data: [
                                { y: 48.9,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 38.8,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 39.3,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 41.4,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 47.0,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 48.3,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 59.0,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 59.6,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 65.2,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 65.2,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 59.3,      drilldown: 'Div3' },
                                { y: 51.2,      drilldown: 'Div3' }
                            ]
                        }],

                        drilldown: {
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Infra',
                                id: 'Div1',
                                series: [{
                                    name: '1',
                                    data: [
                                        { y: 49.9, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 71.59, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 106.4, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 129.2, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 144.0, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 176.0, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 135.69, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 148.5, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 216.4, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 194.1, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 95.6, name: '1' },
                                        { y: 54.4, name: '1' }
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    name: '2',
                                    data: [
                                        { y: 83.6, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 78.8, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 98.5, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 93.4, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 106.0, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 84.5, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 105.0, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 104.3, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 91.2, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 83.5, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 106.6, name: '2' },
                                        { y: 92.3, name: '2' }
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    name: '3',
                                    data: [
                                        { y: 48.9, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 38.8, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 39.3, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 41.4, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 47.0, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 48.3, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 59.0, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 59.6, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 65.2, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 65.2, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 59.3, name: '3' },
                                        { y: 51.2, name: '3' }
                                    ]
                                }]
                            }, {
                                name: 'Industry North',
                                id: 'Div2',
                                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]
                            }, {
                                name: 'Industry South',
                                id: 'Div3',
                                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]
                            }]
                        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

As you can see in the jsfiddle the second and third departments do get a drilldown result, but that's showing just one serie. I need to show multiple series, one for each department within the chosen division.

Comment: So you want to have a drilldown to multiple series from a single point? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939222/single-series-drilldown-to-multiple-series-highcharts

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for. The only difference is that there are indeed multiple series, but only 1 category. Do you have something similar with for example numbers per month?

Comment: So, if you click on a single point you need multiple series (departments) of clicked series (divisions) and on category click you need to have like all series drilled down?

Comment: If yes, then here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/pk544oad/

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I meant :)

Comment: :) Should I add some comments and post it as an answer? or is there something more that you would like to ask?

Comment: If you'd like to see official support for something like this, try casting votes towards [this similar feature](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/6147473-drill-down-charts-that-can-handle-more-than-one-se)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drilldown to multiple series from a single point is already explained here: [Single series drilldown to multiple series Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939222/single-series-drilldown-to-multiple-series-highcharts)

The main challange here is to drilldown into category with each point having mulitple series. For this let's check if first argument of event function in chart's drilldown event has property points defined as array (when drilling down into category) instead of having it set to false (when drilling down into a point).

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
            ...
            if (e.points === false) {
              ... //single point drilldown
            } else { 
              ... //or category drilldown and e.points is array of clicked category's points
            }
            ...
```

Next, load all series for all points as previously, so multiple `chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(point, series);` and `chart.applyDrilldown();` in the end.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pk544oad/