# Can HighChart support multiple graph types in a single drilldown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

From the following fiddle we can implement drilldown in highCharts :http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/

Code:

```
$(function () {

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
});
```

But my requirement is **when you perform a drill down, I need to show multiple charts showing same data**, for example a spline as well as bar chart. I tried a lots of trial and error, but no luck. Is it possible to implement this kind of feature with HighCharts or any other jQuery plugins? Kindly share your thoughts.

My existing graph with HighCharts :

[image]

It's combination of bar and spline.

When I click a bar, this should result in the following drilldown view:

[image]

Please help to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what this would look like? Why have multiple charts with the same data?

Comment: You could drilldown to multiple series and set type for each series in drilldown. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939222/single-series-drilldown-to-multiple-series-highcharts You could also check this demo (drilldown into first column): http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/5/

Comment: Thanks @Kacper Madej. It worked for me.