# How to set plot options in Highcharts in case of drill down

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have just started using Highchart in my project and I am very much new to it.

I am stuck with two scenarios for drill down charts:

**First** I need to show a column chart, and on click of the column I have to show a pie chart with legends. I am looking on below example:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffc4jhb7/115/)

```
legend: {
  enabled: true
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
    }
  },
  showInLegend: true
},
```

**Second** I have requirement to show drill down to three levels: Column chart to Column chart to Column Stacked Chart.  I have not been able to find out a way to set the `plotOptions` correctly to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made first one work like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffc4jhb7/122/). I dont know this is correct way or not

Comment: It is correct. For the second, you might need to reorganise the series to fit the stacking - in this case you might need drilldown to multiple series (with stackign enabled) - see the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939222/single-series-drilldown-to-multiple-series-highcharts